# DC not replicating with other DC's, errors in dcdiag, how can it be fixed without transferring the FSMO and demoting the DC?

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

In my workplace there are two domains;
The first one is the office/IT domain and the second one is production domain and there's a one way trust from production domain to office domain.
One of the production dc's is called DR and it holds the Schema Master and DNS roles of the production domain.
Since about 10 days ago DR server stopped replicating with the other DC's.
Yesterday I've spent some time investigating it and found that Kerberos was giving many error events regarding the password, I've used `netdom resetpwd /s:other_dc` to reset the Kerberos password and when the process finished i was able to successfully replicate.
But today morning I've noticed that the replication failed again while there are no more errors from Kerberos but now I see that there's some problem with DNS.
I'm able to ping between all DC's using hostname/ip .
The output of `dcdiag.exe /v` on the problematic DC (hostname DR) can be found here:
http://pastebin.com/EHVWRpvA
The output of `dcdiag.exe /test:dns` is here:
http://pastebin.com/J63Jncsu
The output of ipconfig /all :

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : DR
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . : DOMAIN.com
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   DNS Suffix Search List. . . . . . : DOMAIN.com
                                       office.local

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : DOMAIN.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : vmxnet3 Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-50-56-B9-37-4B
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.y.yy(Preferred) 
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.4.254
   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.y.yy (same as IP)
                                       10.0.x.x
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.DOMAIN.com:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : DOMAIN.com
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : 
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Teredo Tunneling Pseudo-Interface
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

  [1]: http://pastebin.com/EHVWRpvA
  [2]: http://pastebin.com/J63Jncsu
```

Answer (score 2):

Why bother?  It's usually a lot easier and faster to replace a problematic DC than repair it.  If there isn't a pressing reason to preserve this DC, I'd advise building up a new one to take its place.

Comment: To the OP: And if there is a pressing reason to keep it, my advice after looking at the dcdiag outputs is to open a ticket with MS' Directory services support team.  Why mess with possible fixes when you can have them fix it right and not be in the same mess next week?

Comment: Thanks mate, I think that's what we are going to do... open a support ticket @ Microsoft.